# Gmock Exception - String too long in test body

Tags: c++, googlemock

I have written mocked implementation for a class and everything works fine until I have to check the calls of the function which accepts parameters.

Currently I am using gmock wildcards to say that accept 2 parameters and this is throwing exception

```
unknown file: error: C++ exception with description "string too long" thrown in the test body.
```

Below is the test case body:

```
TEST_F (Test, CheckFunction)
{
   EXPECT_CALL(*ptr, Func1(testing::_, testing:: _)).Times(testing::AtLeast(1));
   EXPECT_TRUE(helperptr->func1("{}", false));
}
```

I have created a test fixture and the objects are getting initialized in setUp.

Any idea why and how this exception is getting raised?

Comment: The phrase "string too long" does not seem to appear anywhere in the Google Test code, are you sure this exception isn't just being thrown by the function you are testing?

Comment: Yes whenever this TestFixture is run it throws this error

Comment: And it's this exception that does not allow the function to be called on mocked object and the expectation and test case fails